# Qt: Can't create floating widget with QVideoWidget as parent?

Tags: qt, pyside, python-3.9, pyside6, qt6

I'm trying to create a floating, layout-less widget but it doesn't seem to work with a `QVideoWidget` as it's parent?

Working MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw

app = qtw.QApplication()
w1 = qtw.QWidget()
w2 = qtw.QWidget(w1)
w2.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
w1.show()
w2.show()
app.exec()
```

Not working MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtMultimediaWidgets as qtmw
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw

app = qtw.QApplication()
w1 = qtmw.QVideoWidget()
w2 = qtw.QWidget(w1)
w2.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
w1.show()
w2.show()
app.exec()
```

The code is supposed to overlay a red `QWidget` over the `QWidget`/`QVideoWidget` but the red `QWidget` is shown only when the parent is a `QWidget`, and not when it's a `QVideoWidget`, why could that be?

Comment: Not sure which of the solutions that work for qt5 will still work for qt6. Probably the best bet is to [use a graphics-view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52602390/984421).

Comment: @ekhumoro Could you still post the solution(s) that worked for qt5 please? I'll have a look at the `GraphicsView` way as well.

Comment: You can [search for them on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20QVideoWidget%20overlay) (e.g. [this random example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48299092/984421)). I don't have any specific examples myself - I just know they exist. My hunch is that many of the qt5 ones probably won't still work with qt6 (due to all the [changes to qt multimedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-changes-qt6.html)). However, the graphics view framework has components explictly designed for the job, so it should work in both qt5 and qt6.

Comment: @ekhumoro Oh, I will do just that then. I did implement this with `QGraphicsView` once before, along with an image viewer so I was able to switch between an image viewer or a video player, but dropped the idea because of a reason I don't quite remember anymore, which is why I asked for the non-`QGraphicsView` examples. Hopefully I don't rediscover the problem I faced before.

Comment: @Neat It seems that the behavior has changed in Qt6: QVideoWidget actually adds a private QVideoWindow (a private QWindow subclass) and adds it using [`createWindowContainer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer), which automatically puts the created widget *on top* of the stacked order and as an opaque box, meaning that there is no way to put anything *above* it.

Comment: @musicamante guess I will have to do it the `QGraphicsView` way then. What I'm creating is a program to both view images and play videos (not simultaneously), would you recommend I add both the `QPixmap` and the `QGraphicsVideoItem` onto a single `QGraphicsView`, switching between the two items when requested, or use two `QGraphicsView`s in a `QStackedWidget` instead, switching between the two `QGraphicsView`s when requested? I'm thinking of going with the latter since I had problems (I can't remember what) trying to implement the former in the past.

Comment: @Neat I cannot give you a proper suggestion, since I don't know the requirement of your program. That said, having a common interface is certainly better: switching between a QGraphicsView and another widget could complicate things, while having a common graphics view interface could be actually useful, while it might require a more complex programming interface on your side at first. Fundamentally, both QGraphicsPixmapItem and QGraphicsVideoItem are very similar, so you could consider writing a common ancestor QGraphicsItem class that has both children, and eventually switch their visibility.

Comment: @Neat also note that, in the rare case the underlying media framework doesn't support a specific image but still supports a more standard one, you can still open the image as a QPixmap, save its buffer as one of the formats compatible with the media framework, and use [`setSourceDevice(buffer, QUrl())`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html#setSourceDevice). In this way you just have a single "video item".